# java FileNotFoundException: class path resource does not exist

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, gradle

При запуске моего web-приложения на java возникает ошибка FileNotFoundException: class path resource [auth/database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist.
При этом путь к файлу указан верно вот мой appconfig-root.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.telegram.aggregator"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:auth/database.properties"/>

<import resource="appconfig-data.xml"/>
```

Сlasspath подсвечен зеленым, он сам подхватывает путь, когда я начинаю его вводить

вот мой appconfig-data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.telegram.aggregator"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="${jdbc.show.sql}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${jdbc.batch}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.telegram.aggregator"/>
```

Ниже представлю структуру проекта

[image: Структура проекта и настройки tomcat]

[image: В варнике есть папка с ресурсами, а в ней мой файл]

Возможно я как-то неправильно собираю?

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

 group 'Telegram'
 version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

 sourceCompatibility = 1.7


 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.github.badoualy:kotlogram:1.0.0-RC3'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot- starter-     data-jpa', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.9.9'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.0'
     compile group: 'org.primefaces', name: 'primefaces', version: '7.0'
     compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-impl', version: '2.2.19'
     compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-api', version: '2.2.10'
     compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.8.RELEASE'
      compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.8.RELEASE'
  }
```

Comment: ну значит ваш auth/database.properties не попадет в джарник

Comment: а каким образом я могу его насильно туда поместить?

Comment: ну у вас как то собирается приложение, там и смотрите, почему ресурсы не попадают

Comment: сейчас посмотрел. Ресурсы имеются

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. Добавил структуру варника и билда gradle

Comment: Проблема так и не решена. По-прежнему не может найти файл с пропертями

Comment: Жду ответа уже с 28 июня. Это уже 3ий вопрос, на который я не получил ответа.. Неужели так тяжело ответить.